# timeout exception with solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using solr (v4) - I am sporadically getting the following exception:

```
Timeout occured while waiting response from server at: http://localhost:8983/solr
```

I am assuming that I can change the timeout parameter through a config file or via my code in solr (which I believe I reduced already a few weeks ago).  Besides changing the timeout period in the config/code (and checking why my code or perhaps solr is taking so long for the connection, is there anything else I can look into to troubleshoot this issue)?

**Update**:
This seems to occur around the time when I try to commit a few documents to solr (which are well defined) - however, a few of them might already be in solr & I'm not sure if that is causing any issues with solr

Edit:
What I mentioned in my first edit seems to be be the case though I am not entirely certain.

Comment: similar thing usually happens when i try to use data import, but it is temporary in my case... can you add more log entries and tell us which container are you using? jetty or tomcat?

Comment: I'm using neither - I'm using solrj to spawn a HttpSolrServer connection.  I will add more info on the exception soon.

Comment: Same thing here. Commit will produce a timeout. Do you have any news on this issue?

Comment: @Tropper  sorry but it was a long time ago - are you sure these are new inserts or are you trying to update an existing object in solr?

Comment: Actually I found my problem. I had an explicit commit() call in my call. And after reading the documentation I learned that this is a bad idea and not needed. Without the commit() call everything works fine. Sorry for the fuzz... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you caching or pooling HttpClient or connection? If so, do you have by any chance a firewall between your client and Solr Server?

It might be a case of long running connection being shut down by firewall and all consequent attempts to use that connection will either get packets dropped (leading to timeout) or get RST packet back.

If you can replicate it, try running Wireshark on the client and seeing what happens to the connection. But if it is firewall, it is usually very hard to replicate (need to create a connection gap of X hours).

Comment: thanks for the feedback - there is no firewall between the apps.  I can run wireshark to confirm which side is dropping the packets though I suspect its solr (I know I need to confirm that).

Comment: Actually, I missed 'localhost'. If they are both on localhost then firewall is unlikely, but also Wireshark will most probably not see the traffic on the loopback. It may actually be easier to troubleshoot by putting one of the pieces on the other machine.